# How do I install Internet Explorer on Windows Server 1803 (semi annual release)?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

The Windows Server 1803 has a very limited set of tools by default. One of the limitations is no pre-installed Internet Explorer. Is there a way to install it somehow on that system? I tried to download the offline installer, but I found only installers for previous versions of Windows.

Comment: Also requesting to add windows-server-1803 as a tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows Server 1803 is only available in Core edition. You can not install Internet Explorer on a Windows Server Core edition, that's the whole point.

If you really need a graphical browser, you can try the portable versions of Chrome or Firefox. They worked on previous versions of Server Core. I haven't tried them on 1803.